# Can you use routing in Angular2 from within class function?

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I know you can use routerList as a directive but I'm curious if in the routeToFramework method below, there would be a way to redirect to a route that is already defined in my RouteConfig. I simplified the code to basically nothing, but hopefully that should be enough.

I'm trying to decouple the routing from another component so that the other component can be bundled and used by other components. This way the route can change for each component that uses this.

```
export class Main {
    constructor() {
    }

    routeToFramework(event) {
        // use routing here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do that with Router class. You need to inject Router in your constructor.

```
export class Main {
 constructor(public router: Router) {}

 routeToFramework(event) {
    this.router.navigate(['./NameOfMyRoute'])
 }
}
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/Router-class.html

Comment: Thank you! When I would look on the angular API docs, I would always find the Router directives and not the class itself. This looks like what I need!